# How to compare dates on minute level in plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

If I'm correct, then date comparison on seconds level is as simple as

```
SELECT 1
FROM sample_table
WHERE sysdate <= sample_table_date_field;
```

but haven't found any simple or stable solution for date comparison on minute level.
If there is, then what would it be?

Comment: `ROUND(yourdate,'MI')`

Comment: @Phil  : or `TRUNC` .

Comment: @Phil: Or perhaps `TRUNC(sysdate, 'MI')` instead (since it's `sysdate <= column` and not the other way round).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TRUNC (date) function which returns date with the time portion of the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model. 
Syntax:

```
TRUNC(date, fmt) or TRUNC(date).
```

Where fmt can be 'DAY', 'YEAR','HH','MI'.
For more format model please refer: [ROUND and TRUNC Date Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084)

Example:

```
SELECT 1 FROM sample_table WHERE TRUNC(sysdate,'MI')<=TRUNC(sample_table_date_field,'MI');
```

Otherwise you can also use `EXTRACT` function to extract the elements from datetime.
Example:

```
SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE extract(minute from systimestamp)=extract(minute from systimestamp);
```